# Nested ListGroup with ELM

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, elm

I'm using the Bootstrap package for ELM (http://elm-bootstrap.info/listgroup) and it's working fine, but I can't figure out how to do nested list group.
Simply puttin ul in li in ul seems to make ugly unclickable inside list with invisible text, which is not ideal.

I guess Accordion would work instead, but it looks way more complicated than a bunch of nested lists.

The goal is basically to have a small file explorer, displaying directories and files on the side of the window (and clicking a directory expands it, so sub-lists elements must be clickable).

What I tried :

```
LG.ul
[
  LG.li [LG.active, LG.attrs [onClick ...]]
  [
    text "test",
    LG.ul [LG.li [LG.attrs [onClick ...]] [text "something"]
  ]
]
```

Basically with that, when the first li is active, "something" shows up invisible (but selectable) but can't be clicked, and visually it's a bid hideous.

Thanks

Comment: Please share the code you want help with - I doubt anyone will click on the link and follow through installing this repo,....

Comment: Well nothing in particular, just looking for a way to make nested listgroup work, so you do need to know this lib to answer I think. I can add a bit of code but it'll be nothing usefull

Comment: If it is a short, self-contained, compilable example http://sscce.org/ that can be ran in ellie https://ellie-app.com/. It would be extremely useful.